# Can't access DataFrame elements after reading from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm creating a matrix and converting it into DataFrame after creation. Since I'm working with lots of data and it takes a while for creation I wanted to store the matrix into a CSV so I can just read it once is created. Here what I'm doing:

```
transitions = create_matrix(alpha, N)
# convert the matrix to a DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(transitions, columns=list(tags), index=list(tags))

df.to_csv(r'D:\U\k\Desktop\prg\F_transition_' + language + '.csv')
df_r = pd.read_csv('transition_en.csv')
```

The fact is that after reading from CSV I got the error:

**in get_loc raise KeyError(key). KeyError: 'O'**

It seems this is thrown by those lines of code:

```
        if i == 0:
            tran_pr = df_r.loc['O', tag]
        else:
            tran_pr = df_r.loc[st[-1], tag]
```

I imagine that once the data is stored in a CSV, the reading of the file is not equivalent to the DataFrame I had before. How can I convert these lines of code to login like I did before?
I tried to set index=False when creating the csv and also skip_blank_lines=True when reading. Nothing changes

df_r is like:

[image: df_r]

Comment: How is your `df_r` like?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh added a pic

Comment: When you use `df_r.loc['O', tag]`, `O` is index, you didn't have `O` in your index.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh and if I set index=False on csv creation, what df_r.loc['O', tag] will search for?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you set when reading csv. `O` is column in your dataframe, by using `df_r.loc['O',tag]`, you are using `O` as index. What do you want to do with `df_r.loc['O',tag]`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I need for eg. to store in tran_pr the value at df_r.loc['O', 'B-ORG'] (0.51954 if tag = B-ORG, look at the pic)

Comment: You can try `pd.readcsv(index_col=0)` or `df = df.set_index('Unnamed: 0')`

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh It seems second one works! I need to do more testing but with the first set of data it's ok! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 3]], columns = ['A', 'B'], index = ['C', 'D'])
print(df['A']['C'])
```

while using loc you need provide index first and then give column

```
df_r.loc[tag, 'O']
```

will work.

Don't use index = false, while importing, which will not include index in the dataframe